# Getx Close to Route automatically getting called

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-getx, flutter-routes, flutter-scaffold

Automatically CLOSE TO ROUTE gettng called deleting the dependencies injected.

the below code is used for navigating to next screen, and when I am clicking the back button provided by scaffold this is the output of log:

- [GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /add_family_history
- [GETX] "CatalogDiseaseRemoteService" deleted from memory
- [GETX] "CatalogDiseaseRepository" deleted from memory
- [GETX] "GetCatalogDisease" deleted from memory
- [GETX] "UpdateFamily" deleted from memory
- [GETX] "AddFamilyHistoryController" onDelete() called
- [GETX] "AddFamilyHistoryController" deleted from memory

and hence again going to the same page gives me

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following message was thrown building Builder(dirty):
"GetCatalogDisease" not found. You need to call "Get.put(GetCatalogDisease())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>GetCatalogDisease())"

the code used for navigation is this:

```
onButtonTap: () {
               Get.toNamed(Routes.addFamilyHistory);
             },
```

and the back button code of scaffold is this:

```
getAppBar1(String value,{List<Widget>? actions, bool? isBackIconEnable = true, bool? elevationDisable=false}) {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: white,
    elevation: elevationDisable!?0.0:0.5,
    title: BaseText(
      text: value,
      textColor:Colors.black,
      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
          fontSize: 14.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          color:  Colors.black),
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    ),
    centerTitle: false,
    leading: isBackIconEnable!?IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset(
          getAssetsPNGImg('Arow'),
        ),
        onPressed: () => Get.back()):const SizedBox(),
    actions: actions,
  );
}
```

Please help me avoid onDelete for dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

where you inject the controller use the attribute permanenet to true to set the the controller saved in memory
like this :

```
 Get.put(GetCatalogDisease(), permanent: true);
```

this error show because the controller is killed from memory for this reason Get,find will not found the controller use the method above or replace Get.find bu Get.put another time